# How to anonymously send money to a seller (without using crypto)?

Tags: money-transfer, cryptocurrency, paypal, transaction

I want to send money to a seller without giving them my info (name, address etc). However, they don't accept crypto. Paypal is an easy option but I heard my personal details get sent to them along with the transaction. I am fine with the platform knowing my info. Both of us are not in USA. So can't use Venmo or Cashapp.

Comment: Mail a money order. Send a Western Union or MoneyGram. Ship precious metal. Or send cryptocurrency.

Comment: Yes, PayPal gives the seller contact information for the buyer. Not credit card number, but name and address, to make shipping whatever is being paid for easier.

Of course this is info you usually want them to have anyway, so you can receive the purchased item.

Comment: probably worth noting you're not trying to hide from the government, just from the seller

Comment: @user253751 Unless they are trying to hide from both. If we're giving them the benefit of the doubt it doesn't need to be said; if we aren't it doesn't matter whether it's said or not.

Comment: Not trying to hide from the government, just from the seller.

Comment: How will the get you your stuff?